# Including jQuery causes standard JavaScript to stop functioning?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting started with jQuery.  I'v been trying to mix it with some of my preexisting JavaScript code so I don't have to rewrite everything.  I have read many places that this is totally doable.  However, whenever i include any lines of jQuery the standard JavaScript stops functioning.

Here's a few examples:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #testjquery {
                height: 300px;
                width: 300px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="testjquery" onclick="testClick()">This is the stuff.</div>
        <script src='jquery-1.10.2.min.js'></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                function testClick() {
                    document.getElementById("testjquery").style.background = "blue";
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This doesn't work, and when clicks I get a function not defined error.

But, putting this in the body

```
<body>
    <div id="testjquery">This is the stuff.</div>
    <script src='jquery-1.10.2.min.js'></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#testjquery").click(function() {
                $(this).css("background", "blue");
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Works fine, as does the equivalent in standard JavaScript.

Comment: When you define "testClick" *inside* the jQuery "ready" handler, it's a *local function* and not visible in the global scope.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't wrap your function in `DOM ready($(document).ready(function(){)` handler.As it is a anonymous  function so your `testClick()` function has `local scope`.So you can  not call it outside the `DOM ready`

```
function testClick() {
    document.getElementById("testjquery").style.background = "blue";
}
```

Read [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope)

Answer (score 5):

The following block is run when the document is ready, and creates a *local* function `testClick()` that is not visible outside of the anonymous function (the one created by `function(){` on the first line).

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
function testClick(){
document.getElementById("testjquery").style.background="blue";
}
});
```

If you want to define a global function that can be called directly, you shouldn't put it inside a document ready handler. Change it to this instead.

```
function testClick(){
  document.getElementById("testjquery").style.background="blue";
}
```